# soundcloud asking for redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm using the Javascript SDK to 1) list albums and 2) play songs on those albums. These will all be public songs.

When I use the example code from the docs https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing

It says `Uncaught Options client_id and redirect_uri must be passed`

Even though the docs say
`Note that as long as the sound is public, you'll only need to provide a client_id when creating a client.`

I also don't see a method for listing albums, but once I get in, I can start exploring. Any ideas on how to get the client to work?

Comment: Soundcloud's api doesn't always work the way they say. I always just create and app & generate a non expiring token to pass with my calls, then it just works. I'm not saying you HAVE to, just some advice from somebody who has made several SC based sites.

Comment: So I did do that, but how do you make calls with a token? All their examples use a client_id

Answer (score 0):

So, The only way I got this working, which was not documented anywhere.

Use `SC.initialize` passing in the `client_id` and any `redirect_uri`. Grab the unsecure non expiring access_token from the URL.

Then, make a call to SC.initilize passing that access_token as the key.

```
SC.initialize({
    access_token: "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
});
```

Then DON'T call SC.connect(). Just start using the api calling SC.get("/me", cb);

Soundcloud... Please provide better documentation. Thumbs down.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a redirect URI as of version 3.3.0 of the JavaScript SDK, just a Client ID:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '{CLIENT_ID}'
});

SC.stream('tracks/107686148').then(function(player) {
    player.play();
});
```